# Cygwin public key location error

Tags: cygwin

Recently we got a new server and transferred the keys from the old server to the new one; however, when running a script on the new server- that works on the old server- I keep receiving this error:

> "decryption failed: No secret key".

On the new server, when looking at "gpg --list-keys", it shows the location of the keys as:

> "C:Users/$USER/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.gpg".

When executing that command on the old server, the location shows that the keys are located in

> "/home/$USER/.gnupg/pubring.gpg".

How do I change cygwin to look for keys in the following location ?

> "/home/$USER/.gnupg/pubring.gpg"

Is that what is causing this error?

Thanks,

Comment: Check that $USER has an entry in /etc/passwd

Comment: Thank you- there is not an entry. How do I create that?